# Error in get("f", environment(CoordMap$train)) : object 'f' not found

Tags: r, ggmap

Previous posts on this question have centered on downloading packages from GitHub.
I have installed the packages (`ggrepel, ggplot2, ggmap, ggforce, ggraph`) from GitHub but still get the following error

```
p <- ggmap(map)
```

> ```
> Error in get("f", environment(CoordMap$train)) : object 'f' not found
> ```

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Only solution I found was to install an older version of ggplot2 library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/ggplot2@v2.2.0")

Comment: I got this error after upgrading from standard distro of ggplot2 to the dev version at tidyverse/ggplot2. I did this upgrade in order to avoid getting a pesky "Error in zero_range(from) : x must be length 1 or 2" error when running coord_proj to transform map data. The coord_proj error went away when mapping with map_data but now cannot map with ggmap.